# How to extract page_source from a webpage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get data from a government webpage, however, when I get the page source, it does not contain the data that is shown in the browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


page = 'http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/#/consultarOferta'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(page)

## Click on "Encerrada"
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div /div[4]/div[2]/label[3]/input').click()


## Select year
year = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/select'))
year.select_by_visible_text('2017')


## Click on "Pesquisar"
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[4]/div[3]/div/a[1]/span').click()


## Click on "DEBENTURES SIMPLES" inside "Ofertas Encerradas"
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#content > div.container.ng-scope > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(15) > td.col-lg-2.text-left.ng-binding').click()

## Click on 1st result
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#content > div.container.ng-scope > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > table > tbody > tr.text-center > td.text-left.ng-binding').click()

##Page Source
html = driver.page_source
```

In this example, the first field "CNPJ", instead of getting the value '04.031.960/00001-70', I get this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength" data-ng-cnpj="" data-ng-model="$responsavel.ofertante.cnpj" data-ng-change="getNomeResponsavelPorCnpj($responsavel.ofertante)" data-ng-disabled="mesmosDadosEmissor || $responsavel.disabled" maxlength="18" disabled="disabled">
```

Also, if I hover over the value in the browser, it is not possible to select it.

Is there a way to get the data from this type of page?

Comment: It's possible to get the data, but probably won´t be easy. I recommend you to use the "Inspector" on your browser and try to reproduce the requests that the web app makes with a library as `requests`. This [blog](https://onlinejournalismblog.com/2017/05/10/how-to-find-data-behind-chart-map-using-inspector/) can give you an idea of how find the data behind the tables.

Comment: may be you need to wait for some times to load the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked this out getting the information from the browser log. The data did not appear directly in the html source, but it was inside the POSTs used during the process.

Here it is the final working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities 
import json
import pandas as pd


page = 'http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/#/consultarOferta'

d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'performance':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d)
driver.get(page)

## Click on "Encerrada"
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div /div[4]/div[2]/label[3]/input').click()


## Select year
year = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/select'))
year.select_by_visible_text('2017')


## Click on "Pesquisar"
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[4]/div[3]/div/a[1]/span').click()


## Click on "DEBENTURES SIMPLES" inside "Ofertas Encerradas"
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#content > div.container.ng-scope > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(15) > td.col-lg-2.text-left.ng-binding').click()

## Click on 1st result
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#content > div.container.ng-scope > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > table > tbody > tr.text-center > td.text-left.ng-binding').click()


## Selenium browser log
performance_log = driver.get_log('performance')

## Find log with allocation information
for j in range(len(performance_log)):
    if performance_log[j]['message'].find('Clubes de Investimento') != -1:
        break

allocation = performance_log[j]['message']

## Filter allocation data
allocation = allocation.replace('\\', '')
allocation = allocation[allocation.find('{"colocacoes":['):]


## Put data into a Pandas DataFrame
allocation_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['tipoInvestidor', 'numeroInvestidores', 'quantidadeValorMobiliario'])
slice_allocation = '{"tipoInvestidor":{"id":' 
slice_alternative= '{"numeroInvestidores":' 

for i in range(1,11):

    beginning = allocation.find(slice_allocation+str(i)) if allocation.find(slice_allocation+str(i))!=-1 else allocation.find(slice_alternative) 
    end = allocation.find(slice_allocation+str(i+1)) if allocation.find(slice_allocation+str(i+1))!=-1 else allocation.find(slice_alternative) 

    allocation_investor = allocation[beginning:end-1]
    allocation = allocation[end:]

    allocation_investor = json.loads(allocation_investor)
    allocation_investor['tipoInvestidor'] = allocation_investor['tipoInvestidor']['descricao']

    allocation_table = allocation_table.append(allocation_investor, ignore_index = True)

allocation_table.fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you `click()` on the *1st result* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *Heading* **** to be visible and then you can extract the **page_source** as follows :

- Code Block :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ng-binding ng-scope'][contains(.,'RIO DE ENCERRAMENTO DE OFERTA P')]")))
  ##Page Source
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt_br" data-ng-app="app" class="ng-scope"><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}</style>  
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
      <meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="Mon, 22 Jul 2002 11:12:01 GMT" />

      <title>Sistema Ofertas com Esforços Restritos</title>

      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/img/favicon.ico" />

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/open-sans.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker/datepicker.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/js/ngTable/ng-table.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/cvm.css" />
  </head>

  <body class="modal-open" style="padding-right: 17px;">
      <div id="fullContent">

          <div id="content" data-ng-controller="AutenticarUsuarioController" class="ng-scope">
          <!-- INICIO MENU BRASIL -->
              <div class="nav-brasil">
                  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                      <div class="container">
                          <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#brasil">
                            <img src="resources/img/brazil-flag_05.png" />
                            </button>
                          </div>

                          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="brasil">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                          <li><a class="icon-brasil" href="http://www.brasil.gov.br/" target="_blank">BRASIL</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://www.acessoainformacao.gov.br/sistema/" target="_blank">Acesso à informação</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                          <li class="first-li"><a href="http://brasil.gov.br/barra#participe" target="_blank">Participe</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://www.servicos.gov.br/" target="_blank">Serviços</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://www.planalto.gov.br/legislacao" target="_blank">Legislação</a></li>
                          <li><a href="http://brasil.gov.br/barra#orgaos-atuacao-canais" target="_blank">Canais</a></li>
                            </ul>

                          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- FIM MENU BRASIL -->

              <!-- INICIO CABEÇALHO -->
              <div id="header">
                  <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-4">
                              <h5>CVM - Comissão de Valores Mobiliários</h5>
                          </div>
                          <div class="text-right" data-ng-init="initContraste()">
                              <a class="h6" href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="altoContraste()">ALTO CONTRASTE</a>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <a class="h2" href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="abrirPaginaPrincipal()">Sistemas de Ofertas Públicas com Esforços Restritos</a>

                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-3">
                              <h5>GOVERNO FEDERAL</h5>
                          </div>
                          <!-- ngIf: temUsuario() -->
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- FIM CABEÇALHO -->

              <!-- INICIO MENU PRINCIPAL -->
                  <!-- INICIO MENU PRINCIPAL -->
              <div class="nav-principal">
                  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                      <!-- ngIf: temUsuario() -->
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- FIM MENU PRINCIPAL -->

              <!-- INICIO CONTEÚDO -->
              <!-- ngView:  --><div data-ng-view="" class="container ng-scope">   
  <div data-ng-init="init()" class="ng-scope">
      <div class="row row-title">
          <div class="right-title">
              <!-- ngIf: acao.isAcaoVisualizar() && permissaoAlteracao -->

              <!-- ngIf: acao.isAcaoVisualizar() && permissaoAlteracao -->

              <a class="btn btn-link" href="ajuda/Envio_Formulario_Encerramento.pdf" target="_blank">
                  <img src="resources/img/ajuda.png" />
                  <span class="ng-binding">Ajuda</span>
              </a>
          </div>

          <!-- ngIf: acao.isAcaoIncluir() -->
          <!-- ngIf: acao.isAcaoAlterar() -->
          <!-- ngIf: acao.isAcaoVisualizar() --><div data-ng-if="acao.isAcaoVisualizar()" class="ng-binding ng-scope">VISUALIZAR FORMULÁRIO DE ENCERRAMENTO DE OFERTA PÚBLICA COM ESFORÇOS RESTRITOS</div><!-- end ngIf: acao.isAcaoVisualizar() -->

      </div>

      <div style="min-height: 1200px">
          <div class="row row-required ng-binding">* Campos Obrigatórios</div>
          <!-- ngIf: acao.isAcaoAlterar() && !usuarioGestor -->       

          <div data-ng-responsavel="$responsavel"></div>
          <div data-ng-oferta="$oferta"></div>
          <div data-ng-intermediario="$intermediario"></div>
          <div data-ng-colocacao="$colocacao"></div>

      </div>

      <div class="row row-center">

          <div class="col-center">
              <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="voltar()">
                  <img src="resources/img/arrow-left.png" />
                  <span class="ng-binding">Voltar</span>
              </a>

              <!-- ngIf: acao.isAcaoIncluir() -->

              <!-- ngIf: acao.isAcaoAlterar() -->

          </div>

      </div>
  </div></div>    
              <!-- FIM CONTEÚDO -->   

          </div>

          <!-- INICIO RODAPÉ -->
          <div id="footer">
              <div class="container footer-container">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-8">
                          <a href="http://www.acessoainformacao.gov.br/sistema/" target="_blank">
                              <img src="resources/img/logo-acesso_25.png" />
                          </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-2 text-right cvm-footer-description">
                          <h6>CVM - Comissão de</h6><h6>Valores Mobiliários</h6>
                      </div>
                      <a href="http://www.brasil.gov.br/"><span class="logo-brasil-footer"></span></a>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="version-sistem">
                  <div class="container">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- FIM RODAPÉ -->

      </div>

      <!-- DEPENDÊNCIAS JAVA SCRIPT -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/base64/jquery.base64.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery/jquery.maskmoney.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/angular/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/ngTable/ng-table.min.js"></script> 

      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/directives/directives.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/message/message.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/message/i18n.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/security/security.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/app.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/AutenticarUsuarioController.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/ConfigurarValoresMobiliariosController.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/EnviarFormularioInicialController.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/EnviarFormularioParcialController.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/EnviarFormularioEncerramentoController.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/EnviarComunicadoDispensaMicroEmpresaController.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/EnviarFormularioDispensaLoteUnicoController.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/GerenciarEnvioFormulariosController.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/ConsultarOfertaController.js"></script>


  <div class="message" ng-messages=""></div><div class="loader modal in" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;"><div class="modal-backdrop  in" style="height: 672px;"></div><div class="modal-dialog"> <div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header" style="text-align: center"><h5 class="modal-title">Aguarde</h5></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="row row-mg-1 row-center"><img src="resources/img/ajax-loader.gif" /></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
  ```